Taxonomy column values not shown in Power Apps Form and Power Automate
i created a taxonomy column to replace an old choice column. I wrote a PowerShell script, which maps the value to the term and updates the item using the PnP PowerShell Cmdlets. The value is there in the grid view, the version history and when i check the value via PowerShell. The field is not populated, when i open the Power Apps Form and it is also missing, when i get the item with the corresponding Action in Power Automate.
Is something wrong with the items, when they are updated? This issue is really troublesome, because we have a lot of lists, where the same column should be changed to the taxonomy version.
When i set the value with the Form and save it, it is there the next time. Has anyone seen this? Help much appreciated.
Regards

I solved the issue myself the following way: i implemented a flow, which sets the value of a taxonomy column and is triggered by the script
